# How to get stack build/install to include resource files (configs, images etc.)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

After having picked up stack as a step in starting to write non-trivial haskell programs (larger than a single file) I've run across the problem of not knowing how to get stack to recognize .ini files and such. It doesn't seem to fit anywhere in the .cabal or stack.yaml files.

For clarification: after running stack build/install, the folder with the generated .exe doesn't have the resources, and so of course the program crashes with a bunch of IO errors (file not found).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two options. The one I assume you're looking for is [data files](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.4/docs/html/Cabal/authors.html#paths-module). To do this, you'll essentially:

1. Add the relevant files to the `data-files` field in your `.cabal` file so that they are installed when building your package
2. Add the `Paths_package_name` module to your `other-modules` in your `.cabal` file (replace `package_name` with your package name)
3. Import that `Paths_*` module where needed
4. Use the generated `getDataFileName :: FilePath -> IO FilePath` function to get the absolute path to the data file you need

The alternative is to embed the data file contents inside the executable itself using Template Haskell, such as with the [file-embed](https://www.stackage.org/package/file-embed) package.

Comment: solved using the data-files field! this is also yet another excuse to get going with exploring template haskell soon ^^

Comment: @michael-snoyman
could you also share how to do this with package.yaml file if I am using hpack? I've been looking how to do it with that and haven't had any luck.

Comment: followup: I experimented a bit and found that adding data-dir: data is enough in package.yaml

I imported Paths_project into my code and everything compiles fine. But what I am confused by is that when I do `stack build`, it doesnt seem to copy the data files to .stack-work/install/... where the executable expects to find it when I use getDataFileName... furthermore when I `stack install`, it copies the built executable, which using its getDataFileName still expects to find the data file in .stack-work/install/...I am very confused. why doesn't stack build copy over the data files.

Comment: @s.kacer you aren't alone. See [this Stack issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1005), it's a bug... although I'm still unsure if it's solved or not.